# K8s tutorial fails on my local installation with i/o timeout

Tags: kubernetes

I'm working on a local kubernetes installation with three nodes. They are installed via geerlingguy/kubernetes Ansible role (with default settings). I've recreated the whole VMs multiple times. I try to follow the Kubernetes tutorials on https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/explore/explore-interactive/ to get services up and running inside the cluster and try to reach them now.

```
# kubectl get nodes 
NAME        STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
enceladus   Ready    <none>   162m   v1.17.9
mimas       Ready    <none>   162m   v1.17.9
titan       Ready    master   162m   v1.17.9
```

I tried it with the 1.17.9 or 1.18.6, I tried it with https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-kubernetes and https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray on fresh Debian-Buster VMs. I tried it with Flannel and Calico network plugin. There is no a firewall configured.

I can deploy the kubernetes-bootcamp and exec into it, but when I try to reach the pod via kubectl proxy and curl I'm getting an error.

```
# kubectl create deployment kubernetes-bootcamp --image=gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1
# kubectl describe pods

Name:         kubernetes-bootcamp-69fbc6f4cf-nq4tj
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         enceladus/192.168.10.12
Start Time:   Thu, 06 Aug 2020 10:53:34 +0200
Labels:       app=kubernetes-bootcamp
              pod-template-hash=69fbc6f4cf
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.1.4
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.1.4
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/kubernetes-bootcamp-69fbc6f4cf
Containers:
  kubernetes-bootcamp:
    Container ID:   docker://77eae93ca1e6b574ef7b0623844374a5b2f3054075025492b708b23fc3474a45
    Image:          gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp@sha256:0d6b8ee63bb57c5f5b6156f446b3bc3b3c143d233037f3a2f00e279c8fcc64af
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 06 Aug 2020 10:53:35 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-kkcvk (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-kkcvk:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-kkcvk
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                -------
  Normal  Scheduled  10s   default-scheduler   Successfully assigned default/kubernetes-bootcamp-69fbc6f4cf-nq4tj to enceladus
  Normal  Pulled     9s    kubelet, enceladus  Container image "gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    9s    kubelet, enceladus  Created container kubernetes-bootcamp
  Normal  Started    9s    kubelet, enceladus  Started container kubernetes-bootcamp
```

**Update** service list

```
# kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   4d20h
```

I can exec curl inside the deployment. It is running.

```
# kubectl exec -ti kubernetes-bootcamp-69fbc6f4cf-nq4tj curl http://localhost:8080/
Hello Kubernetes bootcamp! | Running on: kubernetes-bootcamp-69fbc6f4cf-nq4tj | v=1
```

But, when I try to curl from master node the response is not good:

```
curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/kubernetes-bootcamp-69fbc6f4cf-nq4tj/proxy/
Error trying to reach service: 'dial tcp 10.244.1.4:80: i/o timeout'
```

The curl itself needs ca. 30sec to return. The version etc. is available. The proxy is running fine.

```
# curl http://localhost:8001/version
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "17",
  "gitVersion": "v1.17.9",
  "gitCommit": "4fb7ed12476d57b8437ada90b4f93b17ffaeed99",
  "gitTreeState": "clean",
  "buildDate": "2020-07-15T16:10:45Z",
  "goVersion": "go1.13.9",
  "compiler": "gc",
  "platform": "linux/amd64"
}
```

The tutorial shows on `kubectl describe pods` that the container has open ports (in my case it's `<none>`):

```
Port:           8080/TCP
Host Port:      0/TCP
```

Ok, I than created an apply-file `bootcamp.yml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-bootcamp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kubernetes-bootcamp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kubernetes-bootcamp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubernetes-bootcamp
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
```

I removed the previous deployment

```
# kubectl delete deployments.apps kubernetes-bootcamp --force
# kubectl apply -f bootcamp.yaml
```

But after that I'm getting still the same `i/o timeout` on the new deployment.

So, what is my problem?

Comment: It takes some time to get the cluster running after creating it. wait some time about 5 min, and try again.

Comment: The time has no effect here - of course the example above was "fast generated" but first - you can see, it is "running", the pod exec is working and I tried that several times with fresh installation and "after a lunch" I get still the timeout, even an hour later.

Comment: what is your local installation? Minikube? Is there any firewall between master and worker nodes?

Comment: As I wrote, I'm using the Ansible role https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-kubernetes which installs a "normal" kubernetes with flannel. No - it is not Minikube. All nodes are VMs on the same host (Proxmox) and firewall is disabled. They have bridged network devices. I've updated the question

Comment: I found https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/18079 which is exactly my problem, but neither changing the spec (add containerPort) helped nor adding :8080 in the API URL helped. It looks like on the one side like a bug (in tutorial port is exposed, in my case it isnt) and then some network issue outside the pod.

Comment: show us the output of `kubectl get svc`

Comment: I've updated the question. I don't understand the output. Why is there a 10.96.0.0 address and the nodes have a 10.244.0 flannel network? In real all nodes have a 192.168-network.